# Virtual emulators which can play HD videos in android

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, virtual-machine

Prior to **genymotion** I was using *Android Emulator*. Even though it lagged, it played normal videos.

**genymotion** is very fast, but, sadly, it doesn't play videos. It only completes advertisements. Are there any better options to play videos?

I need to test this with multiple devices.